# Lista contendo apenas o último elemento em Python

Tags: python, lista, arquivo, objetos

Eu estou percorrendo um arquivo de texto e colocando o conteúdo dele em uma lista de objetos, em que
cada objeto contém dois atributos "do tipo string": palavra e significado...
O problema é que a depois que eu percorro o arquivo.txt com o laço for, a lista passa a ter apenas o último elemento inserido. O que poderia estar acontecendo ?

Código:

```
import itemLista
"""
Conteúdo do arquivo itemLista.py

class Item:
palavra = ''
significado = ''

"""

objIten = itemLista.Item()  # Cria um objeto do tipo Item

lista = []

i=0 # variável para controle de índice da lista

try:    
    arq = open('words.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') # abre o arquivo words.txt
    arq.seek(0) # Realinha o ponteiro no arquivo na posição 0
    for linha in arq:
        linha = linha.rstrip() # Retira o caractere '/n' da linha
        vet = linha.split(' ') # Quebra o conteúdo em duas partes (palavra e significado)
        objIten.palavra = vet[0]
        objIten.significado = vet[1]
        lista.append(objIten)
        print(lista[i].palavra,lista[i].significado) # Mostra todos os elementos da lista normal
        i = i + 1
    arq.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Erro ao abrir o arquivo!\n",e)

for item in lista:
    print(item.palavra,item.significado) # Mostra apenas o ultimo elemento da lista várias vezes
```

Comment: Você cria `objIten` uma vez e dentro do laço você só vai alterando os valores. Pro que não cria ele também dentro do laço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma instância individual de `Item` para cada linha processada dentro do seu laço `for`, segue um exemplo comentado:

```
# Objeto Item
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.palavra = None
        self.significado = None

# Inicializa lista de items
lista = []

try:
    # Abre arquivo para leitura
    with open('words.txt', encoding='utf-8') as arq:

        # Para cada linha do arquivo...
        for linha in arq:
            # Remove caracteres de controle do final da linha
            linha = linha.rstrip()

            # Quebra linha em 2 partes (palavra e significado)
            vet = linha.split(' ')

            # Constroi uma instancia do objeto Item
            item = Item()

            # Preenche atributos de uma instancia do objeto Item
            item.palavra = vet[0]
            item.significado = vet[1]

            # Inclui item na lista
            lista.append(item)

    # Exibe Items da Lista
    for item in lista:
        print(f'{item.palavra} => {item.significado}')

except OSError as e:
    print("Erro ao abrir o arquivo: ", e)
```

Entrada (`words.txt`):

```
cat gato
dog cachorro
duck pato
bird passáro
frog sapo
rabbit coelho
ant formiga
bee abelha
snake cobra
horse cavalo
```

Saída:

```
cat => gato
dog => cachorro
duck => pato
bird => passáro
frog => sapo
rabbit => coelho
ant => formiga
bee => abelha
snake => cobra
horse => cavalo
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SourDefensiveCleantech)

Em `Python`, tudo pode ser ainda mais simples:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, palavra, significado):
        self.palavra = palavra
        self.significado = significado

try:
    with open('words.txt', encoding='utf-8') as arq:
        lista = [Item(*linha.rstrip().split()) for linha in arq]

    for item in lista:
        print(f'{item.palavra} => {item.significado}')

except OSError as e:
    print("Erro ao abrir o arquivo: ", e)
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TinyDeliriousAttribute)

Comment: Perfeito! Parece que eu estava inserindo na lista apenas o mesmo objeto instanciado na memória e por mais que alterasse o valor, era uma lista de um objeto só... Kramba vc fez tudo em uma única linha :)  Muitíssimo Obrigado!